# Python timestamp to time since conversion

Tags: python, mysql, unix, timestamp

I have a database column the holds timestamps in UNIX format, I am looking for a way to compare those timestamps to a timestamp from the time right now and print how many seconds/hours/days since the original timestamp.

Just to confirm I am NOT looking for a conversion from `1489757456` to `03/17/2017 @ 1:30pm`. I AM looking for a conversion from `1489757456` to `1m ago/2hr ago/3d ago` ect.

Answer (score 1):

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()
```

to convert your unix timestamp to a datetitme

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

to get the current datetime

```
dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(dt1, dt2, ...)
```

to get the difference with respect to leap years.

**References**:

- https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html
- http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

Answer (score 1):

Function, like this will generate output for hours, mins and seconds from seconds number.

```
def secondsToHms(d):
    d = int(d);
    h = math.floor(d / 3600)
    m = math.floor(d % 3600 / 60)
    s = math.floor(d % 3600 % 60)

    htext = " hour, " if h == 1 else " hours, "
    hDisplay = str(h) + htext if h > 0 else ""
    mtext = " minute, " if m == 1 else " minutes, "
    mDisplay = str(m) + mtext if  m > 0 else ""
    stext = " second" if s == 1 else " seconds"
    sDisplay = str(s) + stext if s > 0 else ""
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay;
```

For example:

```
secondsToHms(344334)
>> 95.0 hours, 38.0 minutes, 54.0 seconds
```

So you can add your preferred formatting and also add days/months if needed in similar fashion.